# Unable to get gulp autoprefixer working

Tags: gulp, gulp-sass

I'm currently setting up a new project with gulp and I cannot get gulp-autoprefixer to work.

Below is my gulpfile.js so far.

```
var gulp = require('gulp'),
    sass = require('gulp-sass'),
    prefix = require('gulp-autoprefixer'),
    rename = require('gulp-rename'),
    livereload = require('gulp-livereload'),
    sourcemaps = require('gulp-sourcemaps');

gulp.task('styles', function() {
  gulp.src('css/**/*.scss')
    .pipe(sourcemaps.init())
    .pipe(prefix('last 2 version'))
    .pipe(sass().on('error', sass.logError))
    .pipe(sourcemaps.write('./'))
    .pipe(rename({suffix: '.min'}))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./css/'));
});

gulp.task('default',function() {
  gulp.watch('css/**/*.scss',['styles']);
  livereload.listen();
  gulp.watch(['./**/*']).on('change', livereload.changed);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Managed to fix it, see below.

```
var gulp = require('gulp'),
    sass = require('gulp-sass'),
    autoprefixer = require('gulp-autoprefixer'),
    rename = require('gulp-rename'),
    livereload = require('gulp-livereload'),
    sourcemaps = require('gulp-sourcemaps');

gulp.task('styles', function() {
  gulp.src('src/css/**/*.scss')
    .pipe(sourcemaps.init())
    .pipe(sass().on('error', sass.logError))
    .pipe(autoprefixer({
      browsers: ['last 2 versions'],
      cascade: false
    }))
    .pipe(sourcemaps.write('./'))
    .pipe(rename({suffix: '.min'}))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./dist/css/'));
});

gulp.task('default',function() {
  gulp.watch('src/css/**/*.scss',['styles']);
  livereload.listen();
  gulp.watch(['./**/*']).on('change', livereload.changed);
});
```